# KeyPress Event using ChrW

Tags: vb.net, winforms, performance

I have written a little game in VB.NET using Visual Studio. It's a "type the alphabet as fast as you can" game.

The User Control displays all of the letters from A to Z and when you press the key on the keyboard associated to that letter (In the correct order from A to Z) it will become grayed out.

*Here is the code that I have written so far:*

```
Public Class UserControl_Alphabet

    Public Shared CurrentKey As Integer = 65

    Private Sub UserControl_Alphabet_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(CurrentKey) Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(CurrentKey + 32) Then

            ' This section of the code will gray out labels
            Select Case CurrentKey
                Case 65 : Label_A.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
                Case 66 : Label_B.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
                Case 67 : Label_C.ForeColor = Color.LightGray
                ' AND SO ON...
            End Select

            CurrentKey += 1

                If CurrentKey = 91 Then
                    MsgBox("Done")
                End If

            End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

**My questions are:**

1. Is there an easier way to change colors on the labels without having a case for each letter. All Labels are named in sequential order, Label_A, Label_B, Label_C, etc.

I have tried `(Label_ & ChrW(CurrentKey)).ForeColor = Color.LightGray` but that doesn't work.

2. The code `If e.KeyChar = ChrW(CurrentKey) Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(CurrentKey + 32) Then` feels very sloppy. There must be a better way to write this. I tried using a `KeyDown` event instead of a `KeyPress`, but that meant that I couldn't use `ChrW`. To my understanding `KeyDown` isn't case sensitive as `KeyPress` is, which is the reason to why I need to use ChrW for both the low cased and upper cased letter.

Comment: Me.Controls("Label_ & ChrW(CurrentKey)).ForeColor = ...  Consider using Char.ToUpper() to avoid the unreadable CurrentKey + 32 and selecting the wrong control.

Comment: @HansPassant That works perfectly! Consider writing an answer so that I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Put your labels into a lookup table and use the Keycode of your letter as index.

Try something like this:

```
Public Class UserControl_Alphabet

    Public Shared CurrentKey As Integer = 65
    private labels As Label() = {Label_A, Label_B, Label_C}

    Private Sub UserControl_Alphabet_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

        If e.KeyChar = ChrW(CurrentKey) Or e.KeyChar = ChrW(CurrentKey + 32) Then

            ' This section of the code will gray out labels
            labels((CurrentKey-65) Mod labels.length).ForeColor = Color.LightGray

            CurrentKey += 1

                If CurrentKey = 91 Then
                    MsgBox("Done")
                End If

            End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

**Addition:**
You could also use a Dictionary instead of an array. This way you wouldn't have to calculate something based on your return value and yould also use, let's say' numbers.
However, if you only use A-Z, there is nothing wrong with a lookup table.